# How to set a variable in Install4j

Tags: java, install4j

I have compiler variable called MyVariable.
In a script I set this -

`context.setVariable("MyVariable",new String("szzz"));`

However, when I use this variable it has not changed its value

`System.out.format("var %s!!!\n",context.getCompilerVariable("MyVariable"));`
outputs the original value

Running he debug version of my installer shows that the variable has been changed

I am confused and would appreciate a clarification

Thanks

Graham Labdon

Answer (score 1):

Your mixing two different variable systems.

`Context#setVariable` sets and installer variable, `Context#getCompilerVariable` gets the value of a compiler variable.

Compiler variables are fixed at compile-time, they cannot be changed at runtime. Use

```
 context.getVariable("MyVariable")
```

to get the value of the installer variable.